# Install the libidn.so.11 library for 32-bits in a 64-bit system

Tags: software-installation, shared-library

With 13.04 I installed `ia32-libs` to pick up dependencies for a specific 32-bit application that I use. There is no `ia32-libs` for 14.04.

I need ONE library, `libidn.so.11`. Here's my summary:

First ...

```
me@myW510:~/opt/FS/bin$ ./SLVoice
./SLVoice: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I installed `lib32z1` using synaptic, and this was resolved.

Next ...

```
me@myW510:~/opt/FS/bin$ ./SLVoice
./SLVoice: error while loading shared libraries: libidn.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm pretty sure this will be the last lib I need.

What should I install? Do I need to add a repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ia32-libs` and friends have been obsoleted by multiarch support. The proper way to install a 32-bit lib on a 64-bit system is now to install `PACKAGENAME:i386`, so in your case `libidn11:i386`.

Comment: Specifically, for SLVoice I installed the following: lib32z1, libidn11:386, libuuid1:i386, and libstdc++6:i386 (no :386 on the lib32z1).  SLVoice works now.  THANKS!!

Comment: Further investigation revealed that SLVoice needs more :i386 libs.  In addition to the libs above, I installed pavucontrol:i386, which added about 45 megabytes of additional libs.  NOW SLVoice works.